# Tableau - Percentage Difference in Count From Prev. Month

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to display the percentage diff in count from the previous month. I get the correct values with no filters.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIhy7.png)

But when I filter by selecting a month, I don't get the % difference from the previous month.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt4fO.png)

Attached, please find the workbook.

Comment: what is the formula used?

Answer (score 0):

% difference from previous month is based on the lookup function. If you filter on the month then this will get impacted based on the months available. If your calculation is returning incorrect result then check the Edit Table option and see how the table computation is calculated (Table down, across etc) and select the correct option. Hope this helps.